# Find all matches of a pattern and replace them in a text file

Tags: python

From the text file with contents below:

```
NPAD2077    छर्नअघि\V_VM बिउलाई\N_NN दुई\QT_QTC भाग\N_NN गरेर\V_VM छिट्टो\JJ उमार्नका\V_VM निम्ति\PSP एक\QT_QTC रात\N_NN पानीमा\N_NN भिजाइन्छ\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
NPAD2078    पन्ध्र\QT_QTC दिनका\N_NN अन्तरालमा\N_NN सिँचाइ\N_NN गर्नुपर्छ\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
NPAD2079    पातलाई\N_NN उम्रिएको\V_VM १५\QT_QTC -\RD_PUNC २०\QT_QTC दिनमा\N_NN ध्यानपूर्वक\N_NN चुँड्नुपर्छ\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
NPAD2080    प्याजको\N_NN दाना\N_NN सुप\N_NN ,\RD_PUNC सस\N_NN अथवा\CC_CCD अचार\N_NN बनाउँदा\V_VM अनि\CC_CCD सब्जीमा\N_NN उपयोग\N_NN गरिन्छ\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
NPAD2081    उत्‍तम\JJ खेतीका\N_NN निम्ति\PSP एकदमै\QT_QTF तातो\JJ ,\RD_PUNC चिसो\JJ अथवा\CC_CCD पानी\N_NN हुनु\V_VM हुँदैन\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
NPAD2082    बारी\N_NN राम्ररी\RB जोतेर\V_VM चाँहिदो\JJ लम्बाइ\N_NN अनि\CC_CCD चौडाइको\N_NN ड्याङ\N_NN उठाउनु\V_VM पर्छ\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
NPAD2083    बिउलाई\N_NN रबी\N_NN फसलका\N_NN निम्ति\PSP अक्टोबर\N_NN -\RD_PUNC नोभेम्बर\N_NN अनि\CC_CCD खरिफ\N_NN फसलका\N_NN निम्ति\PSP अप्रेल\N_NN -\RD_PUNC जुनमा\N_NN रोप्नुपर्छ\V_VM ।\RD_PUNC
```

How to remove all the  NPAD20** terms?

Comment: use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.sub) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

res = []
with open(filename) as infile:                        #Open file for read
    for line in infile:                               #Iterate Each line
        res.append(re.sub(r"NPAD\d+\s*", "", line))   #Remove NPAD* from line

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:               
    for line in res:
        outfile.write(line)                            #Write line back to file
```

Answer (score 1):

Command line to the rescue:

```
sed 's/NPAD20.. *//' file
```

Comment: I like this answer. I like you.

Comment: Haha, Unix oneliners sometimes affect people that way. :)

Comment: @AsiisPradhan, in what way is not working? The command should work for the example you gave in your question. You are not trying to run this from Python, right?

Answer (score 0):

Simple two-liner:

```
with open(infile,'r') as f, open(outfile, "w") as f2:
   f2.writelines([i.split()[-1] for i in f.readlines()])
```

Answer (score 0):

If every string in the first column starts with `NPAD20` you can blindly discard the first column:

```
open('outfile', 'w').writelines(l.split(maxsplit=1)[1] for l in open('infile', 'r'))
```